# Why doesn't `git remote set-url` set me remote repository properly?

Tags: git

Github is clear that it doesn't accept user names:

https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

I try to set my remote repository as follows:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:organization/reponame.git
```

When I do

```
git remote -v
```

it then shows

```
origin  git@github.com:organization/reponame.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://username@github.com/organization/reponame.git (push)
```

Why does my push URL still have a username?

Comment: Do you have pushinsteadof rules set or something?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, after:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:organization/reponame.git
```

you would see both fetch and push URLs set to the same string.  Since you are *not* seeing that, something must be slightly abnormal to begin with, and it's easy to predict what that is: you must have already set a `--push` URL in some (any) way.

If you look inside `.git/config` (or run `git config --edit`, which will open the file in your default editor), you would typically see this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:organization/reponame.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

(some values may be somewhat different).  If you set a separate push URL using `git remote set-url origin --push bad://url`, however, you will see that the middle section now reads:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:organization/reponame.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = bad://url
```

If you now use `git remote set-url origin` to change the *fetch* URL, you will see that the *push* url remains set to whatever it was set to earlier.  That is, until you use `git remote set-url origin --push`, the `bad://url` entry will stick around.  You can remove it in various ways, or override it.

Removing it manually, or with:

```
git remote set-url origin --push --delete bad://url
```

and then running `git remote -v` will show that the push URL is now defaulted to the fetch URL.

Because fetch and push are so old (dating back to before Git version 1.5), there are a lot of old compatibility hacks in this area.  [o11c mentioned `pushInsteadOf` in a comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737143/why-doesnt-git-set-me-remote-repository-properly#comment90435021_51737143)  This does not appear to be reflected in `git remote -v` output, however.